# Delete Dynamic Disk in DOS

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I screwed up my hard drive using Disk Management in Windows 7 because i accidentally converted my entire hard drive basic to dynamic. I tried tweaking it around to regain the Basic state, but failed.

Now I can't even boot Windows. Is there a way for me to delete the entire dynamic disk, convert to basic, and start over with the Windows installation in DOS mode?

Comment: Start over in "DOS mode"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [DISKPART](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415), which will allow you to delete dynamic disks. You can access it either through WinPE or the recovery command prompt from a bootable Windows CD.

Answer (score 1):

See this Microsoft article for a step-by-step description of the process:

[Change a dynamic disk back to a basic disk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776315%28WS.10%29.aspx).

If Windows won't boot, you will need to boot from CD into the console.

Answer (score 1):

DISKPART

Run it from the recovery command prompt.

Once there: diskpart

Use ? for help.

I find the clean command is best for removing unwanted (DYNAMIC) drives.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regualuar windows cd to delete the partitions and then you recreate your partitions.  so you can find the instructions using a windows xp cd [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313348)

Comment: i've tried this method, but the delete button is grayed out during installation...